# Using livestreamer to record in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, twitch

i'm having a really hard time trying to figure this out since i don't code in python or use linux. So my problem here is this, i have a python script the will run checking if there's a user online on twitch, if he is livestreamer will start recording. Works just fine in Windows, but now i'm trying to make work on linux ubuntu and i have this error:

```
File "billowy.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()   File "billowy.py", line 76, in main
    dir_path = '%s\livestreamer\livestreamerrc' % os.environ['APPDATA']   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 631, in
__getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'APPDATA'
```

Full script: http://pastebin.com/tDVrwcmh

Comment: https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: What is the value of `os.environ['APPDATA']` on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Copy file 'livestreamerrc' for Windows in Linux ~/.livestreamerrc or create new file `touch ~/.livestreamerrc`

b. Line 76

```
dir_path = '%s\livestreamer\livestreamerrc' % os.environ['APPDATA']
```

change

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    dir_path = '%s\livestreamer\livestreamerrc' % os.environ['APPDATA']
elif os.name == 'posix':
    dir_path = '%s/.livestreamerrc' % os.getenv("HOME")
```